# Java httpClient API request with SSL certificate

Tags: java, authentication, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to connect to an API that requires basic auth + certificate for it to respond with 200 OK.
The basic auth part is pretty simple, i create the Basic token with Base64 encoding and then append the value as a 'Authorization' header to the request.
Code example:

```
String auth = username + ":" + password;
byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(
                auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

...

HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder
                    .get()
                    .setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader)
                    .setUri(URI.create(uri))
                    .build();
```

I am however in a pickle with the certificate part.

I have a .crt and a .key file, directly from the owner of the server that i want to connect to.
I have imported these files into postman to test the request, and it works.
My approach was to create a .p12 and a .jks file and create an SSLContext using that, and then append that context to the Apache HttpClient.

I keep getting error 403 forbidden though, as if the certificate is wrong.
Code sample:

```
KeyStore readStore() {
        try (InputStream keyStoreStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(KEYSTOREPATH)) {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12"); // or "PKCS12" or "JKS"
            keyStore.load(keyStoreStream, KEYSTOREPASS.toCharArray());
            return keyStore;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException | KeyStoreException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error with the keystore creation: ",e);
        }
}

...

        SSLContext sslContext;
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadKeyMaterial(readStore(), KEYPASS.toCharArray())
                    .build();

            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients
                    .custom()
                    .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                    .build();
            HttpUriRequest request = RequestBuilder
                    .get()
                    .setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader)
                    .setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "*/*")
                    .setUri(URI.create(uri))
                    .build();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } catch (IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | SecurityException | KeyStoreException | KeyManagementException
                | UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error during httpClient request: ",e);
}
```

The request get correctly executed, but it always returns error 403 - forbidden, regardless of if i use the .p12 or the .jks file.
I have used portecle to make sure that the .crt file is actually inside the keystore, and it is.

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any exception stack trace apart from 403 status?

Comment: Nope, i get to the response.getStatusLine() print without any exceptions.
Exceptions arise if i change the keyPasswords, so it's not that either, the file gets read correctly..

Comment: Does your JKS & PKCS12 prints all entries while using `keytool` command? Code looks ok to me so far.

Comment: You mean by using 'keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks'? If yes, then yeah, it says there are 2 certificates inside the keystore, and one of them is the one i'm trying to use.